# Error while creating custom dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to create a custom dialog box with two spinners (`spinner_month` and `spinner_year`).

For guidance, I took the sample provided in Google dev guide.

MainActivity code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(R.layout.calender_view);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_month);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.months_array,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My calender_view.xml is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/layout_category"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:padding="5dp">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_year"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_month"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter) on a
>   null object reference

This is because the 'spinner' object is `null`, but I'm not sure why. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.calender_view, null, false);
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_month);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.months_array,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This answer is all code. Please consider adding some descriptions as to why this answer resolves the problem.

Comment: as per the suggestion - 
I added the LayoutInflater and then inflated the `calender_view` and assigned the same to the adapter

It worked perfectly !

Comment: when i call `builder.show`  the first time, it works fine. but subsequent calls fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent`

so is my assumption correct that i need to create the dialog everytime i need it and not something which i can create during `onCreate()` and just simply call  `builder.show()`, which i feel would be more efficient

Comment: Create Dialog every Time when you need